# Embed private Google Spreadsheet

Tags: embed, google-sheets

I'm trying to work out the best way to display a Google Spreadsheet in the members section of a website.

Although the info in the spreadsheet isn't hugely sensitive, I'm not keen on publishing it and embedding it using an iFrame, so am trying to find a way to embed the spreadsheet while still keeping it private.

I've tried using the Spreadsheets API (via the PHP Zend library) with some success, but it seems to fall apart if a lot of the cells are empty. As I'd also ideally like to keep any cell styling, does anyone know of a way to embed the spreadsheet via an iFrame or similar without publishing it?

Any PHP/Javascript solutions most welcome!

Comment: In Google Sites, you can present private data throughout the domain, and it requires a login.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's a member's area - you can use the GDATA AUTH method (part of the php Zend Library) to ensure authentication - even if it is private (you don't need to publicly publish your spreadsheet) - I'm sure you already know this.

If you just want to pull the data - the documents list query and then by use of tables and add CSS to it to retain styling can help.

google: google spreadsheet api IBM - and there's a tutorial that shows a few examples. Hope that helps.